# Simple POST using Lumen

Tags: php, post, lumen

I have in routes.php the following method:

```
$app->post('insertGender', function ($NAME) {
        $result = DB::insert("INSERT INTO HK_GENDER (NAME) VALUES (?)",[$NAME]);
        return ($result)? "wow":"Noo";
    });
```

I try to pass the parameter via form using Postman
[image]
and I get an error

```
Missing argument 1 for Closure::{closure}()
in routes.php line 93
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}('2', 'Missing argument 1 for Closure::{closure}()', '93', array()) in routes.php
at Closure->{closure}()
```

Why is the parameter provided not used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to get the data from the request, like this:

```
$app->post('insertGender', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        $NAME = $request->input('NAME');
        $result = DB::insert("INSERT INTO HK_GENDER (NAME) VALUES (?)",[$NAME]);
        return ($result)? "wow":"Noo";
    });
```